# How to extract train and validation sets in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I implement a neural net in `keras`, with the following structure:

```
model = Sequential([... layers ...])
model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=...)
hist=model.fit(x=X,y=Y, validation_split=0.1, epochs=100)
```

Is there a way to extract from either `model` or `hist` the train and validation sets? That is, I want to know which indices in `X` and `Y` were used for training and which were used for validation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keras [splits the dataset](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/ed204e116d6e8f8dc1f700a6f6f2026c6437c420/keras/engine/training.py#L1666) at

```
split_at = int(x[0].shape * (1-validation_split))
```

into the train and validation part. So if you have `n` samples, the first `int(n*(1-validation_split))` samples will be the training sample, the remainder is the validation set.

If you want to have more control, you can split the dataset yourself and pass the validation dataset with the parameter `validation_data`:

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, …, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y))
```